# Is it true when set does NOT contain 0?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

A, B are convex, closed sets with not empty intersection.

$A^{\circ}$ is polar set of A.

Is it true:

$\overline{conv(A^{\circ} \cup B^{\circ})} = (A \cap B)^{\circ}?$

I was thinking that it is true and was trying to prove it as for case where sets contained 0 using property $(A \cup \{0\})^{\circ}= A^{\circ}$. I find hint in one article. It was something about circle segment without zero. I don't understand what to do with this fact.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Sorry, it's a typo.

Comment: You should probably add more context: what kind of space are you considering?

Comment: @Captain Lama I consider Euclidean spaces.

Comment: what happens if you apply the definition of polar cones? in what space is $A,B$ contained?

Comment: @supinf A, B in some Euclidean space and $A^{\circ}, B^{\circ}$ in that space

Comment: @Captain Lama Can you explain me answer for this question, please?  it's hard for me to find solution.